# Printing the content of current directory c++

Tags: c++, dirent.h

I am trying to simulate the behavior of ls command.

I have created a simple code using dirent.h library

```
    DIR *dir;
    dirent *pdir;
    dir=opendir(".");
    while((pdir=readdir(dir)))
    {
        cout<< pdir->d_name << endl;
    }
    closedir(dir);
```

My current directory contains two files , Screen.cpp and a.out. I would like this code to print it in order , as `ls -la` command would e.g

```
.
..
a.out
Screen.cpp
```

however this code outputs it like

```
.
Screen.cpp
..
a.out
```

Is there any simple method how to achieve so without storing/sorting the list in some container?

Comment: pretty sure `readdir` offers no guarantees about the ordering of its returns. (whether it be inode, disk location, date added, or whatever)

Comment: i am not allowed to use unix system commands

Comment: Its not that hard. With a tiny bit of work you could convert `readdir` into an iterator. Then it becomes a total of three lines to read sort and print the entries.

Comment: What is meant by "container"? Does your assignment spec consider a dumb old string array to be a "container"?

Comment: @user4581301 yes it does :/

Comment: You have a problem then. To order stuff you have to maintain a history. You can't tell if a is before b if you've forgotten b. I'd go back and reread the requirements. Something is missing or has been misinterpreted. You might have to ask for a clarification. Perhaps this is a misguided way to ask for a linked list.

Comment: `ls -la` reads from the filesystem using `readdir()`, stores the results and **sorts**; use `ls -lf` to show the original order.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no you can't do it reliably without storing and sorting the values.

I would wrap the `DIR` library so I could use them as iterators.

```
MyCPPDir   dir(".");
std::set<std::string>  objects(dir.begin(), dir.end());
std::copy(objects.begin(), objects.end(),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

Comment: @lolofon: If you take 10 minutes you can wrap dirent lib in a C++ wrapper that treats a directory like a range. Thats what `MyCPPDir` is.

Comment: I don't know about this feature yet. Thank you.